# Positioning an element on the page

Tags: html, css, navigation, position, program-entry-point

I am new to html and css and I am trying to make a simple page. Unfortunately I have difficulties placing my main under the navigation menu. Maybe I want to place it around 100px under the navigation menu.
I tried with changing the positions to relative, absolute etc. But I have almost no idea what I am doing.
The issue is, that even when I give my main a nice position, when I fill it with lots of content, it goes automatically up (doesnt expand only the bottom part) and goes over the menu and hides it. I try to "lock" somehow main's top part to be always on the same distance from my navigation. If I put a lots of text inside my main, I want it to expand its bottom part and not change its position.

My code is here: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G1M05IYUPR2H.

Can someone give me an advise how to do it? Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G1M0W1037H57

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body, html {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      background-color: black;
    }
    
    .bg-image {
      background-image: url("http://www.stix.bg/wp-content/themes/stix-theme/images/stix1.jpg");
      filter: blur(8px);
      -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      position: absolute;
      margin-top: -300px; /*compensate for margin below*/
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .navigation {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 15%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      width: 80%;
      font-family: Arial;
      border-radius: 10px;
      justify-content: space-around;
      display: flex;
      border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    main {
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
      border-radius: 10px;
      position: relative;
      left: 50%;
      margin-top: 200px; /** <--set distance here**/
      transform: translate(-50%);
      width: 80%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    ul li {
      float: left;
      text-decoration: none;
      list-style: none;
    }
    
    a,
    a:visited {
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    a:hover, a:active {
      color: white;
      background-color: rgba(162, 44, 255, 0.5);
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      font-weight: bold;
      box-shadow: inset 0 -4px 20px 2px rgba(162, 44, 255, 1);
    }
    
    .link {
      padding: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .link2 {
      padding: 10px;
      border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .link3 {
      padding: 10px;
      border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    p {
      text-align: center;
      margin-left: 25px;
      margin-right: 25px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bg-image"></div>
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="link" href="#"> Menu 1 </a></li>
      <li><a class="link2" href="#"> Menu 2 </a></li>
      <li><a class="link2" href="#"> Menu 3 </a></li>
      <li><a class="link2" href="#"> Menu 4 </a></li>
      <li><a class="link3" href="#"> Menu 5 </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <main>
    <h1 style="font-size:30px">Text here</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. removed `position:relative` of `.bg-image`,  added `position:absolute` to main and gave top to align it. thanks

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
}

.bg-image {
    background-image: url(http://www.stix.bg/wp-content/themes/stix-theme/images/stix1.jpg);
    filter: blur(8px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
 }     
 .navigation {
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
   position: absolute; 
  left: 50%;
  top: 15%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: 80%;
  font-family:Arial;
  border-radius: 10px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
}
main {
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 310px;
}
a, a:visited{
  color:white;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor:pointer;
}
a:hover, a:active {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(162, 44, 255, 0.5);
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -4px 20px 2px rgba(162, 44, 255, 1); 
}
.link {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.link2 {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.link3 {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div class="bg-image"></div>
<div class="navigation">
<a class="link" href="#"> Menu 1 </a>
<a class="link2" href="#"> Menu 2 </a>
<a class="link2" href="#"> Menu 3 </a>
<a class="link2" href="#"> Menu 4 </a>
<a class="link3" href="#"> Menu 5 </a>
</ul>
</div>
<main>
<h1 style="font-size:30px">Text here</h1>
  <p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```